# Wordpress page PHP snippet to fetch all requests to subdirectories

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I am developing a PHP snippet for a Wordpress website page. Imagine this snippet is at a page located at

```
wp-example.com/abc
```

But when I call

```
wp-example.com/abc/def
```

Wordpress assumes it is a totally different page and says page does not exist, and my snippet is not applied.

In my PHP snippet, located at `wp-example.com/abc`, how can I fetch all the requests to subdirectories `example.com/abc/**`?

edit: I don't want to amend my web server configuration, I want to do that purely within Wordpress

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this by addding to `.htaccess` file 2 lines: (not tested)

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?abc/(.*)$ /abc [R,L]
```

Comment: thanks, but I don't want to touch my web server configurations, I want to do that purely with Wordpress

Answer (score 1):

Use this .htaccess code.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /abc/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /abc/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: thanks, but I don't want to touch my web server configurations, I want to do that purely with Wordpress

Answer (score 1):

**Step 1: Allow Multisite**

To enable the Network Setup menu item, you must first define multisite in the **wp-config.php** file.

Open up wp-config.php and add this line **above** where it says *That's all, stop editing! Happy blogging..* If it doesn’t say that anywhere, then add the line somewhere above the first line that begins with require or include:

```
/* Multisite */
define( 'WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true );
```

**Step 2: Installing a Network**

The previous step enables the **Network Setup** item in your **Tools menu**. Use that menu item to go to the **Create a Network of WordPress Sites** screen.

To see an example of the Create a Network of WordPress Sites screen, look at **Administration >Tools > Network Setup**. The screen does not look exactly the same in all circumstances. The example shown is for an installation on localhost, which restricts the options available.
https://prnt.sc/28ZPHhke7ZuQ

**Step 3: Enabling the Network**

To enable your network, follow the instructions on the Create a Network of WordPress Sites screen. The instructions that you see are customized for your installation. They might not be the same as the examples you see here.
https://prnt.sc/XBGn0dUbWMJR

Add the first code snippet to your **wp-config.php** directly above the line
The snippet looks like this, but adapted to your own site:

```
// Example code but it is not the code of your website
define('MULTISITE', true);
define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', true);
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'My Website');
define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/');
define('SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
define('BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
```

Add the second code snippet to the **.htaccess** file and replace other WordPress rules.

```
// Example code but it is not the code of your website key
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```